# Hundreds of program files appear in Windows Server 2019 with "2023-09-22 13-11 Copy of "prepended

Tags: windows, file-permissions, windows-server-2019

These files have appeared mostly in the Windows system folders, e.g. under C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSInfo\ there's "2023-09-22 13-11 Copy of msinfo32.exe"

There are hundreds of these all over the MS folders (Window, System32, etc.)

Most can be deleted if CMD as Admin, but a many are System owned.

Q: Why are they there? And how can the system owned be deleted.

Comment: Can you check in various logs what happened on that date and time to create those files? Was there a system or application update? See https://cloudinfrastructureservices.co.uk/how-to-check-windows-server-logs-windows-event-log-types/

Comment: I tried copying more `msinfo32.exe` which created files with names like `msinfo32 - Copy (2).exe`. So your case is different. Did you try deleting one of the copies?

Comment: Looking at the date, 2023-09-22, there was a system restore done on the server.  Looks like it created 900+ files prepended with the 'Copy Of'.  So this isn't a newbie confusion about files that create Copy (2) etc.

The problem now is that most of them are owned by TrustedInstaller so cannot be deleted.  Tried running explorer.exe using ExecTI but Windows won't allow the deletion even with Explorer (supposedly) running as TrustedInstaller.